# Internationalization of 'collapse','open','close' buttons tooltips of primefaces layout

Tags: jquery, primefaces, internationalization

Is there a way to internationalize the tooltips of the little buttons of a primefaces `layoutUnit`?

I use

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="70" style="border: none" />

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50" collapsible="true">
        <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" minSize="80" maxSize="250" size="220" header="#{messages.label_menu_header}" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true" effect="drop">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    ...
</p:layout>
```

and the tooltips for the buttons which collapse,close or open the layout are always in english !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `p:layoutUnit` there are options:

```
closeTitle="" 
expandTitle="" 
collapseTitle="" 
resizeTitle=""
```

where it is possible to use a resource bundle to diplay internationalized messages.